# Zuul proxy with eureka returning 504 Timeout

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have this scenario where I have an Eureka server, a Zuul proxy and the eureka's clients (some API).

The thing is that when I call the Zuul server it does discover the "service" on Eureka but it returns a 504 status time out.

```
{
   "timestamp":"2020-07-21T18:38:46.408+00:00",
   "status":504,
   "error":"Gateway Timeout",
   "message":""
}
```

In my application.properties I have:

```
spring.application.name=zuul-server

eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true

zuul.ignored-services=*
zuul.host.time-to-live=-1
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=15000
zuul.host.max-per-route-connections=10000
zuul.host.max-total-connections=5000
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=60000
zuul.semaphore.max-semaphores=500
```

I can't figure it out what's wrong to cause this timeout.

Any helping tips?

Answer (score 3):

For those who eventually face this same problem here is how I solved it.

This is how my final `application.properties` on the Zuul project is set and working:

```
spring.application.name=zuul-server

eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true

#zuul.ignored-services=*
#zuul.host.time-to-live=-1
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=60000
zuul.host.max-per-route-connections=10000
zuul.host.max-total-connections=5000
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=60000
zuul.semaphore.max-semaphores=500
zuul.ribbon.eager-load.enabled= true

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=40000

ribbon.ConnectTimeout=10000
ribbon.ReadTimeout: 10000
```

If your IDE complains about "unknown property" just ignore it.